# Scroll to bottom of listbox wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, scrollviewer

I have many items(0-100) end need to scroll to the bottom of Listbox which contains it.I tried:

```
ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(listmy, ScrollBarVisibility.Auto);
            listmy.SelectedItem =  listmy.Items.Count-1;
            listmy.ScrollIntoView(listmy.SelectedItem);
            ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(listmy, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
```

but this doesn't workds for me.The scrollviewer wraps the listbox and textbox.(listbox vertical scroll in disabled state).
UPD xaml:

```
<Grid>

    <ScrollViewer Name="_ScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanel" Height="auto">
          <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  x:Name="listmy">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>...
```

and cs:

```
listmy.ItemsSource = ((App)Application.Current).DIALOG;
        ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(listmy, ScrollBarVisibility.Auto);
        listmy.SelectedIndex =  listmy.Items.Count-1;
        listmy.ScrollIntoView(listmy.SelectedItem);
        ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(listmy, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
```

Comment: What does this mean: "The scrollviewer wraps the listbox and textbox" ?  You have a ListBox (which will have its own internal ScrollViewer) and an Outer ScrollViewer of your own?

Comment: How about posting some XAML to show the layout of your UI? As currently worded, your question makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good in english.I posted code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gather you actually want to just ensure the ScrollBar of the ListBox is always fully scrolled to the bottom. The other solutions are only about making sure the last line is visible (not the same thing).

To get the effect you want you can create a simple subclassed ListBox like this:

```
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    namespace ScrollBarTest
    {
        public class CustomListBox : ListBox
        {
            public void ScrollToBottom()
            {
                var scrollviewer = GetTemplateChild("ScrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
                scrollviewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollviewer.ScrollableHeight);
            }
        }
    }
```

*Do not use an outer ScrollViewer as you are in the example, just the subclassed ListBox*

Just call the ScrollToBottom() method whenever you want it scrolled to the last line.

The reason for the subclassing is that `GetTemplateChild` is `protected` so not accessible from outside of a derived class.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
var lastItem = listmy.Items[listmy.Items.Count - 1];
listmy.ScrollIntoView(lastItem);
```

I tried it on a sample project and it worked great!

Comment: I've uploaded my sample project to http://chriskoenig.net/upload/ScrollToBottom70.zip.  I've also verified that this works in both SDK 7.0 and SDK 7.1.  Look at the sample and see if that works - if it does not, perhaps I don't understand your question after all :-)

Comment: I need scrolling in my project. Sample code :`ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(listmy, ScrollBarVisibility.Auto);
          var lastItem = listmy.Items[listmy.Items.Count - 1];
listmy.ScrollIntoView(lastItem);
          ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(listmy, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);`

Comment: I guess I really don't know what you're trying to do, and putting a ListBox in a ScrollViewer just doesn't seem like a good UX metaphor to me.  Is there a sample project I can download somewhere to see what you're trying to accomplish, because I'm obviously not understanding what you're trying to do...

Comment: It's not working well. Imagine your source keeps List of strings. And strings can be be repeated. You code scroll only for the first found item.

Answer (score 2):

Came across this one and haven't found the "works out of the box no code-behind" solution, so I just came up with this class:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

/// <summary>
/// A list box which automatically scrolls to the last line if new items were added.
/// </summary>
public class AutoscrollListBox : ListBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The on items changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">
    /// The e.
    /// </param>
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ScrollDown();
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Scrolls to the last element.
    /// </summary>
    private void ScrollDown()
    {
        if (this.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var lastItem = this.Items[this.Items.Count - 1];
            this.ScrollIntoView(lastItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Just use this listbox and no additional "magic" is required.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply just set the select index of the ListBox, it should work. I tried it, and it seemed to work fine.

```
listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
```

I've tried that, and it scrolled to the bottom of the ListBox, with no problems.